# How to do Case Sensitive authentication in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: zend-framework2

using ZF2 authentication,

use Zend\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable as AuthAdapter;
use Zend\Authentication\Result;

The authentication works.. But When we provide credentials it not case sensitive. The Username and Password will accept any Case.

Can you Suggest any solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your database table, set the `Collation` value for the `username` column to be treated as case-sensitive i.e. by setting it to `latin1_general_cs`.

Please check, when `varchar` is selected as `Type` then the `Collation` is set as `latin_swedish_ci` - which is case-insensitive.

No need to change anything in the code.

Just change the database table part and the Authentication Service is return as Invalid Username.

I hope it helps.

Comment: That's good to know. Can you please accept the answer as correct (tick) so that this question won't get listed in the unanswered list.